# What does it mean that function parameter packs are always pack expansions, so their declared types must include at least one parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

In this snippet

```cpp
template<typename... Types>
void f(Types ... args);
```

`Types` is the *template parameter pack* and `args` is a *function parameter pack*.

Concerning the two technical terms, [*C++ Templates - The Complete Guide 2nd Edition*](https://www.amazon.it/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0321714121/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=Josuttis+templates&qid=1625075076&sr=8-1) reads

> Unlike template parameter packs, function parameter packs are always pack expansions, so their declared types must include at least one parameter pack.

What does that mean? What is the example of non-*at least one*, i.e. zero in the context of that sentence?

Comment: Zero is not possible, as the sentence says, it must be at least one... So there's no example.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, would you say that `x =;` is not an example of an assignment lacking the RHS? It is. And it is wrong code, but nonetheless an effective example to show what lacking the RHS in an assigment means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says that a function parameter pack can only be created using another  parameter pack, rather than from scratch.

> What is the example of non-at least one, i.e. zero in the context of that sentence?

E.g. `int ...params` is illegal, because it doesn't contain any existing packs.

Comment: And "int..." vs "Types..." is both valid, but one creates C varargs function, and the other an unnamed function parameter pack.